# Local Tomcat in IntelliJ - Cannot run program catalina.bat

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, catalina

I have created Local Tomcat (8.5.15) run configuration in IntelliJ IDEA (2019.2). I am running Windows 10. When I try to run the configuration, I get error:

```
Error running 'Local Tomcat': Cannot run program "C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.15\bin\catalina.bat" (in directory "C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.15\bin"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

Environment variables are set:

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221
CATALINA_HOME=C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.15
```

%JAVA_HOME%\bin and %CATALINA_HOME%\bin added to PATH

In Run/Debug Configurations -> Startup/Connection, Startup script and Shutdown script are set to valid paths:

```
C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.15\bin\catalina.bat run
C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.15\bin\catalina.bat stop
```

When run from terminal, Tomcat starts correctly.

I have replaced catalina.bat with some mock script (just echo sth) as Startup script in run configuration, got the same error.
No other logs are visible in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

Changing system environment variable **ComSpec** does the job. 
In my case I had two `cmd.exe` configured 32 bit and 64. 
I removed 32 bit and it started working. Look out as after edit - there might be `;` that also need to be removed.
[image: Screen capture of my settings]